# How to create list of instances deriving from a base class that implements interface?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

Consider the following interface and class declarations.

```
public interface IMessage
{
    string Body { get; set; }
}
public abstract class MessageBase : IMessage
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
public class MessageA : MessageBase { }
public class MessageB : MessageBase { }
public class MessageC : MessageBase { }

public interface IMessageProcessor<T> where T : IMessage
{
    Action<T> ProcessorAction { get; set; }
}
public abstract class MessageProcessorBase<T> : IMessageProcessor<T> where T : MessageBase
{
    public Action<T> ProcessorAction { get; set; }
}
public class MessageAProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageA> { }
public class MessageBProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageB> { }
public class MessageCProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageC> { }
```

Now I want to declare a list of processor instances like so, but cannot figure out what generic type will allow me to add any derived processor type to the list.

```
var processors = new List<???>();
processors.Add(new MessageAProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageBProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageCProcessor());
```

I have tried:

```
// compiles but throws InvalidCastException
var processors = new List<IMessageProcessor<IMessage>>();
processors.Add((IMessageProcessor<IMessage>)new MessageAProcessor());
```

and

```
// compiles but throws InvalidCastException
var processors = new List<IMessageProcessor<MessageBase>>();
processors.Add((IMessageProcessor<MessageBase>)new MessageAProcessor());
```

and

```
// won't compile
var processors = new List<MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase>>();
processors.Add((MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase>)new MessageAProcessor());
```

What should the type of this list be? I know I must be missing something obvious here. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce `IMessageProcessor` and inherit all your Processors from it. In list you would have to use this interface.

```
public interface IMessage {
    string Body { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MessageBase : IMessage {
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class MessageA : MessageBase {
}

public class MessageB : MessageBase {
}

public class MessageC : MessageBase {
}

public interface IMessageProcessor<T> where T : IMessage {
    Action<T> ProcessorAction { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MessageProcessorBase<T> : IMessageProcessor<T> where T : MessageBase {
    public Action<T> ProcessorAction { get; set; }

    public void ProcessMessage(IMessage message) {
        var msg = message as T;
        ProcessorAction(msg);
    }
}

public interface IMessageProcessor {
    void ProcessMessage(IMessage message);
}

public class MessageAProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageA>,IMessageProcessor {
}

public class MessageBProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageB>,IMessageProcessor {
}

public class MessageCProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageC>,IMessageProcessor {
}
```

And Processors:

```
var processors = new List<IMessageProcessor>();
processors.Add(new MessageAProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageBProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageCProcessor());
```

Comment: You can move `ProcessMessage` implementation to base: `var msg = message as T`

Comment: @3615 Thanks - seems obvious now that I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no inheritance relationship between `ISomething<Type1>` and `ISomething<Type2>` you can't have list of objects that contain mix of those types.

Only real option is to force some base type - either use `List<object>` or better have base non-generic interface for `IMessageProcessor<T>` like `IMessageProcessor<T> : IMessageProcessor`.

Unfortunately it also means you can't have access to properties/arguments using generic type without casts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but your code will indeed not work.

I did the following:

```
public class MessageAProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase> { }
public class MessageBProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase> { }
public class MessageCProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase> { }
```

And then:

```
var processors = new List<MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase>> ();
processors.Add(new MessageAProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageBProcessor());
processors.Add(new MessageCProcessor());
```

will work.

The problem is that

```
public class MessageAProcessor : MessageProcessorBase<MessageA> { }
```

is too specific, and you can't cast this back to `MessageProcessorBase<MessageBase>` in the `List<>`.